# GeoServer wfs-update {https://domain.com/workspace}ParticelleStrade is read-only

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I'm trying to make wfs-insert and wfs-update workable for my hosted GeoServer.
I have made sure following things

1. user auth I'm passing has role as Admin
2. in WFS service level - Complete
3. in Data for *.*w, ADMIN is available
4. taking body reference from the demo request from local

WFS update body looks like

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Update typeName="WS:ParticelleStrade">
    <wfs:Property>
      <wfs:Name>FOGLIO_NUMERO</wfs:Name>
      <wfs:Value>0481</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:FeatureId fid="ParticelleStrade.8405147"/>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

but getting following error

```
     Request: getServiceInfo
2023-07-11 14:28:34,141 WARN [geotools.xsd] - Sax parser property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' not recognized.  Xerces version is incompatible.
2023-07-11 14:28:34,144 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request [WFS 1.1.0 Transaction] starting, processing through flow controllers
2023-07-11 14:28:34,144 INFO [geoserver.flow] - Request control-flow performed, running requests: 1, blocked requests: 0
2023-07-11 14:28:34,146 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException:  {https://domain.com/workspace}ParticelleStrade is read-only
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:240)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor607.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out - `Xerces version is incompatible.` seems to suggest you don't have a working XML Parser chain. This could be a java version issue GeoServer is tested using Java 11, or it could be related to your servlet container but you don't say what you are using. Not entirely clear if GeoServer can recover from that issue.

Secondly, `Feature type 'ProcedureEdilizie' is not available:` - You ask for `<wfs:Update typeName="DIP:ProcedureEdilizie">` in your request but you have declared `xmlns:DIPAU="https://domain.com/geoserver/DIP"` which is different so you end up with a mismatch and no feature found.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion xmlns:DIPAU="https://domain.com/geoserver/DIP" , It is infact xmlns:DIP="https://domain.com/geoserver/DIP"